# Data Annotations Custom Validator not working (as I'd expect) in MVC2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Before I start ... I can't easily migrate the project to MVC3. So.

The problem I'm having is that I've defined a custom validator attribute to check the max AND min length of a string property, *StringLengthInRangeAttribute*.

When the Controller calls *ModelState.IsValid*, on a list of *Passengers*  only the validation of a Date property is throwing invalid, when nothing has been supplied. I guess that means my problem is not with the custom validator but all validation?

#### Update (additional info for clarity):

I have two symptoms of this problem :
1.The Required validator on the *strings* doesn't fire when they are *empty*
and
2.My custom validator never gets called (a breakpoint I set never gets hit).

#### Model:

```
 public class Passenger
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages.Passenger),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequireNumber")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages.Passenger),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequireSurname")]
    [StringLengthInRange(MinLength = 2, MaxLength = 30, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages.Passenger),
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "MaxLengthSurname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
 }
```

#### Custom Validator:

```
public class StringLengthInRangeAttribute:ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinLength { get; set; }
    public int MaxLength { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (((string)value).Length < MinLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (((string)value).Length > MaxLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Controller Action:

```
 public ViewResult TailorHoliday(List<SearchAndBook.Models.ViewModels.Passenger> passengers, 
        int leadPassengerIndex)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("PassengerDetails", GetBookingState(_currentSession));
        }
    //...
    return View();
   }
```

Any advice appreciated. This is the first time I've used Data Annotations, so I'm quite prepared to feel stupid for missing something!

Comment: Are your DateTime nullable? If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Is your validation method called on validation? Can you set a breakpoint?

Comment: @alexn : the fact that it throws an error on a null date value is as expected. I would have thought that the required attributes on Passenger.Surname would throw 'invalid'

Comment: @slfan: No it doesn't get called, I don't understand why!

Comment: Where is this "date" property on which a validation is getting called? Is it also on the Passenger object?

Comment: I think I've mislead everyone. There is a dateOfBirth property on the passenger to and it does get validated as expected (if its null / empty it fires) - everything else, including my custom validator seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the content of the ModelState property (in the debugger) you should be able to see every property that gets validated in `ModelState.Keys` and for each value you see the actual state in the `ModelState.Values`. If I look at your controller you seem to post a whole list of passengers. You should check as well, whether your values are really posted (use Firebug or Fiddler). Maybe your fields are outside the form.

Maybe you should show part of your view as well to spot the bug.